# Remove Id from sObject

Tags: apex, soql, dml

I have the following code:

```
myObject__c customObj =[Select Name,Account__c from myObject__c where id='a06R0000002fMqY'];
insert customObj;
```

The issue is: I'm not querying the `Id` field, the `customObj` has the record `Id` in it.

Is there a way to remove the Id from `customObj`?

I'm looking to have a better solution to handle. the other way you can deal with this situation is that, create a new `myObject__c` without the `Id` in it. 
Creating a new object instance and populating all fields one by one but its too tedious and error prone I have like half dozen objects.

Any better solution?

Comment: `SObject.clone` https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm

Comment: @JesseMilburn Just post that as an answer! Wouldn't take much longer to put a snippet together.

Comment: You can also now assign null directly to Id...

Comment: @sfdcfox: How would you assign null directly to Id ?

Comment: @NickKahn See my answer. Clone also works, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two choices: assign null to Id, or SObject.clone.

## Assign Null To Id

```
myObject__c customObj = [Select Name,Account__c 
                         from myObject__c where id='a06R0000002fMqY'];
customObj.Id = null;
insert customObj;
```

## Clone

```
myObject__c customObj =[Select Name,Account__c 
                       from myObject__c where id='a06R0000002fMqY']
                       .clone(false);
insert customObj;
```

Comment: Might be better to make that second example three lines as well, it requires scrolling on my screen.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Sure thing. Didn't realize it was so long.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `SObject.clone` method:

**Method Signature:**

> clone(preserveId, isDeepClone, preserveReadonlyTimestamps, preserveAutonumber)

```
myObject__c customObj = //your select;
myObject__c cloneObj = customObj.clone(false, false, false, false);
```

**Note:**

> For Apex saved using SalesforceAPI version 22.0 or earlier, the default value for the preserveId argument is true, that is, the ID is preserved.